# Split a column with comma delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a table with 3 columns with the data given below.

```
ID |  Col1        |         Col2            |   Status
1     8007590006    8002240001,8002170828        I
2     8002170828    8002000004                   I
3     8002000001    8002240001                   I
4     8769879809    8002000001                   I
5     8769879809    8002000001                   I
```

`Col2` can contain multiple comma delimited values. I need to update status to C if there is a value in `col2` that is also present in `col1`.

For example, for `ID = 1`, `col2` contains `8002170828` which is present in `Col1`, `ID = 2`. So, status = 'C'

From what I tried, I know it won't work where there are multiple values as I need to split that data and get individual values and then apply update.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET STATUS = 'C' 
WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col2 FROM Table1)
```

Comment: Can there ever be more than two CSV values in `Col2`?

Comment: @tim I'm thinking yes - he said *Col2 can contain multiple comma delimited values*

Comment: @geek what version of sql server please? Cross apply String split will make this a doddle but only available in 2016+

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. It can contain multiple values. 1 or 2 or 3 or any number. Not fixed.

Comment: @CaiusJard i am using 2014

Comment: If Col2 in row 1 matches Col1 in row 3, which row gets marked as C? I read the question to mean the former, but your SQL does the latter.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, then [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) comes in handy:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, Col1, value AS Col2
    FROM Table1
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Col2, ',')
)

UPDATE t1
SET Status = 'C'
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col2;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I am using SQL server 2014. That's why I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is intended as a supplement to Tim's answer

As you don't have the native string split that came in 2016 we can make one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.STRING_SPLIT
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') as value
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
        + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
        + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO

--credits to sqlserverperfomance.com for the majority of this code - https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings
```

Now Tim's answer should work out for you, so I won't need to repeat it here

I chose an xml based approach because it performs well and  your data seems sane and won't have any xml chars in it. If it ever will contain xml chars like > that will break the parsing they should be escaped then unescaped after split

If you aren't allowed to make functions you can extract everything between the RETURNS and the GO, insert it into Tim's query,tweak the variable names to be column names and it'll still work out

Comment: No, my problem was that I defined `Table1` in the demo as a CTE, which can't be updated.  Once I defined a bona-fide table, it worked.